# SQL multiple sum by PARTITION

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following postgreSql table `stock`, there the structure is following

```
| column |  pk |
+--------+-----+
| date   | yes |
| id     | yes |
| type   | yes |
| qty    |     |
| fee    |     |
```

table looks like this

```
|    date    |  id | type | qty  | fee |
+------------+-----+------+------+------+
| 2015-01-01 | 001 | CB04 |  500 |    2 |
| 2015-01-01 | 002 | CB04 | 1500 |    3 |
| 2015-01-01 | 003 | CB04 |  500 |    1 |
| 2015-01-01 | 004 | CB04 |  100 |    5 |
| 2015-01-01 | 001 | CB02 |  800 |    6 |
| 2015-01-02 | 002 | CB03 | 3100 |    1 |
|            |     |      |      |      |
```

I want to create a view or query, so that the result looks like this.

```
|    date    | type | t_qty | total_weighted_fee |
+------------+------+-------+--------------------+
| 2015-01-01 | CB04 |  2600 |                2.5 |
| 2015-01-01 | CB03 |  3100 |                  1 |
|            |      |       |                    |
```

what I did is this

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/39fb8a/18

But this is not the output what I want.

The **Sub Query** table looks like this:

`% of total Qty` = `qty` / `t_qty`

`weighted fee` = `fee` * `% of total Qty`

```
|    date    |  id | type | qty  | fee | t_qty | % of total Qty | weighted fee |
+------------+-----+------+------+-----+-------+----------------+--------------+
| 2015-01-01 | 001 | CB04 |  500 |   2 |  2600 |           0.19 |         0.38 |
| 2015-01-01 | 002 | CB04 | 1500 |   3 |  2600 |           0.58 |         1.73 |
| 2015-01-01 | 003 | CB04 |  500 |   1 |  2600 |           0.19 |        0.192 |
| 2015-01-01 | 004 | CB04 |  100 |   5 |  2600 |           0.04 |        0.192 |
| 2015-01-01 | 002 | CB03 | 3100 |   1 |  3100 |              1 |            1 |
|            |     |      |      |     |       |                |              |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation . . . I don't think you are far off:

```
select date, type, sum(qty),
       sum(fee * qty * 1.0) / nullif(sum(qty), 0)
from t
group by date, type;
```

Comment: getting `SQL Error [22012]: ERROR: division by zero` with my original db

Comment: @as-if . . . If seems odd that `qty` would sum up to zero, but that is easily fixed using `nullif()`.